# Creating a marquee from long text fields in a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a news style ticker (or marquee) from textfields. These text fields can differ in size from very short to very long, it's user input from somewhere else.

The mark-up, created by a view in Drupal, is like this (it would be very hard to change this specific mark-up without having to change a lot of other things as well, I can add classes though):

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="view view-rolkrant view-id-rolkrant view-display-id-block marquee view-dom-id-c1e3f4dba935dd8caed9b69fdd8f91b2">
  <div class="view-content">
    <div>
          <span class="berichtGroen">Door de seizoenstop gaan er geen trainingen voor de V-groepen en klein bad meer door. We starten terug de week van 5 september. Prettige vakantie! En voor trainers en zwemmers een succesvolle examenperiode!</span>    
    </div>
    <div>
           <span class="berichtPaars">Weer een geboorte in de club, en deze keer een eerste kleinzoon voor de voorzitter! Proficiat aan de ouders en grootouders.</span>    
    </div>
    <div>
           <span class="berichtPaars">Regeling trainingen schoonspringen juli en augustus 2016</span>    
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The css I'm using is this:

```
.marquee div{
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
box-sizing: border-box;
animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}

.marquee div:hover {
animation-play-state: paused
}

.marquee div div{
width: auto;
display:inline;
}

@keyframes marquee {
0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
100% { text-indent: -105em }
}
```

This works pretty well, but the problem is that if the total amount of text is too much not everything is shown.
I don't know if I'm missing something or if it's just not possible with purely css. Maybe I need some jQuery or javascript, but most plugins seem to have the same  problem as my css.

Comment: Show us with actual tons of text (lorem ipsum would be great), with the actual HTML structure your are using, since the code you posted does not reflect the problem you describe.

Comment: I've added my actual mark-up with my actual text. I thought that would be best. Most classes (beside marquee) are automatically added classes from  Drupal, except the classes in my span. Those just add a color to the text. The marque stops and restarts after "Regeling" in the third span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [nicolallias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2375207/nicolallias) who say that the text is shown entirely also when the total amount of it is too much. 
However I must point out that the animation behavior is incorrect because when the amount of text is too much, so the length of the container div is greater than the length of the screen, the animation not start from the right of the screen.

To solve you can follow one of these solutions:

- Using HTML & CSS [following this link](http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa)
- Using HTML marquee tag: `<marquee>text</marquee>`
- Using Jquery:

```js
$('.scroll').marquee({
  duration: 15000,
  pauseOnHover: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">text</div>
```